# Wordpress Plugin Dev: Using array for WP options

Tags: array, options

I am busy dabbling with writing a WP plugin and hitting a bit of a problem.

I believe its best practice to store wp options to an array rather than individually which is great no probs.

I have two pages. Page one which updates for example:

```
$xyz_options['api_user']; 
$xyz_options['api_key'];
```

Page two which say has:

```
$xyz_options['site_bgcolor'];
$xyz_options['site_fontcolor'];
```

However when updating from either of the pages it empties the other pages settings when using the built in wordpress form building and so forth. I am wondering if I would be better breaking away from the built in methods would be best or is there another way using WP methods that I have missed.

A quick example. Say I first set `api_user` and `api_key` with `1` and `abc123`. Then go to style page and update `site_bgcolor` with `#fff` and `site_fontcolor` with `#000` it updates the colors but the `api_user` and `api_key` values vanish from the `$xyz_options` array pulled from `wp_options`.

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks guys in advance any pointers would be great.

Comment: Don't overwrite the array. Get the existing one first, then update it with the saved options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Settings API then you don't have to save the options, that's done for you. So when using an array to store the options your validation function should get an array of all existing options, update only the changed and return that array.

Something like this:

```
function my_settings_option_validate( $input ) {
    //do regular validation stuff
    //...
    //...

    //get all options
    $options = get_option('my_plugin_options');
    //update only the neede options
    foreach ($input as $key => $value){
        $options[$key] = $value;
    }
    //return all options
    return $options;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will give it a go and let you know how I get on. Much appreciated.

Comment: Worked a treat mate :-) Spot on! Many many thanks.

Comment: Glad i cloud help :)